# Returning search results for different language

Tags: php

I have a simple site with a dropdown that has primary options like apple, bananas, pears etc, the user selects the option and clicks search and the site returns results where the article primary tag matches the option, it's done using a simple Primary_Tag=Primary_Option condition. This is in English, a user has come along and wants to install a copy of the site and change apple, bananas, pear to the arabic language so apple becomes تفاحة in the dropdown and in his articles. But he gets no search results although he has tagged articles as تفاحة
The rest of the site stays the same and has UTF-8 character encoding which I believe supports Arabic text. So why is this not working and can it work?

Edit 1 - Sample code

```
$Primary_Option = preg_replace('/^-|-$|[^-a-zA-Z0-9 ]/', '', $_GET['primary_option']);
```

then

```
'key' => 'primary_tag',
'value' => $Primary_Option,
'compare' => 'LIKE'
```

then

```
if ($results->have_posts())
```

Comment: UTF-8 definitly support arabic characters. Could you post some code sample ? Problem lies in the code

Comment: @unex have added some sample code snippet

Comment: Your question is about querying posts in Wordpress, right?

Comment: @LarsBeck yes and no it's the same for general PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Just realised it was the preg_replace that was causing the issue.